# Renaming & moving files Using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

sorry since i don't know how to code in VBA . i need help create a Code that do the following .

- I have 2 columns A : old names , B : New names
- I have 2 folders W : Old folder , Z : new Folder
- I want the script to go and use the cells that exist in column A and search for files in Folder W and rename them using the new names in column B
- then move to folder Z ( each file renamed move to folder Z one by one )
- if the file already exist in Folder Z add a number before extension in this manner

Filename (number).extension

why i want it this way ?

I have many audio files that got random numbers on them in folder W and many of files got the same name even though the audio is not the same , so i want each time a file is renamed in folder W to be moved to folder Z and check if a file with excat filename exist if so , add a number before the end just like above .

P.S. i already got files with numbers on them ....(5).ogg so i want the code to be able to read the number 5 and add 6 automatically just like windows does . i have something like 8k files.

I hope the you guys got the general idea and sorry i don't code in VBA . nor do i understand it .

Comment: Do the mentioned names have extension, too? Do the two folders contain the ending backslash ("\")?

Comment: yeah all of them have extension , dunno about folder what do you mean ? P.S. this is in windows so they aren't ending with blacklash

Comment: The folder paths **is a string**. It may be ending in backslash or not, according to your will... So, I can deduce that it does not ends in backslash. I mean you can use: `W = ThisWorkbook.path` or W = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"` . And you build the full file name using `W & "\" & "fileName"` or  `W & "fileName"` for the second case...  Just to make the code more compact. Now, could be more then one occurrence for a file name already existing in `Z`? I mean, to use `oldName & "V1" & ".extension`. Should the renaming function take in consideration more than one such occurrence for a file?

Comment: yeah . they should be more than 1 occurrence that means you gotta set it up for a loop if i'm not wrong . as far as folder goes they are not ending with backslash the files exist inside the folder ex: C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder Z

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. Not immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using the next code. It needs you to set the correct value to `oldPath` and `newPath` variables. I used two such variables only to test the code on my environment. It will only return in C:C column information about the moved/copied files:

```
Sub testMoveChangeName()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrM, i As Long
 Dim oldName As String, newName As String, oldPath As String, newPath As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
 arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array, for faster iteration
 ReDim arrM(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)  'set dimensions for the array to keep the processing feedback
 
 oldPath = ThisWorkbook.Path: newPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NewFolder" 'please, adapt here, using your necessary paths
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                            'iterate between the array rows:
    oldName = arr(i, 1): newName = arr(i, 2)         'extract the file names from the array
     
    If Dir(oldPath & "\" & oldName) <> "" Then       'if the combination folder path = file name from the sheet is not wrong:
           If Dir(newPath & "\" & newName) = "" Then 'if not any file with such a name:
               Name oldPath & "\" & oldName As newPath & "\" & newName  ' Move and rename file.
               arrM(i, 1) = "Moved"                                                                           'place the moving status in the array
           Else       'if a file with that name already exists in the new folder:
                 newName = newNm(newName, newPath)                       'rename the new file
                 Name oldPath & "\" & oldName As newPath & "\" & newName ' Move and rename file.
                  arrM(i, 1) = "Moved (with version)"                                                'place the moving status in the array
           End If
    Else
           arrM(i, 1) = "File not found" 'in case of bad old file path
    End If
 Next i
 'drop the status array content at once:
 sh.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrM), 1).Value2 = arrM
End Sub

Function newNm(strExisting As String, strFold As String) As String
    Dim arrFiles, arrSuffix, arrName, nrSuffix As Long, i As Long, maxSuffix As Long
       arrName = Split(strExisting, "."): strExisting = arrName(0) 'the name without extension
       arrFiles = getAllF(strFold & "\" & strExisting & "*." & arrName(UBound(arrName))) 'place all files matching the path - name combination in an array
       
       If UBound(arrFiles) = 0 Then                    'if only one file has been found:
                newNm = strExisting & " V01." & arrName(1): Exit Function 'change its name
        Else                                             'if more files have been found:
                For i = 0 To UBound(arrFiles)            'find maximum numeric suffix:
                        arrName = Split(arrFiles(i), "."): strExisting = arrName(0)
                        If IsNumeric(Right(strExisting, 2)) Then
                            arrSuffix = Split(strExisting, " V"): nrSuffix = CLng(arrSuffix(1))
                            If nrSuffix > maxSuffix Then maxSuffix = nrSuffix
                        End If
                Next i
                If maxSuffix > 0 Then
                    newNm = arrSuffix(0) & " V" & Format(nrSuffix + 1, "00") & "." & arrName(1)
                Else
                    newNm = strExisting & " V01." & arrName(1)
                End If
        End If
End Function

Private Function getAllF(strFold As String, Optional strExt As String = "*.*") As Variant
    Dim arrFiles
    arrFiles = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    arrFiles(UBound(arrFiles)) = "@@##": getAllF = filter(arrFiles, "@@##", False) 'remove the last (empty) array element
End Function
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

**Edited**:

Please, use the next procedure to return the number of occurrences for each new Name existing in "B:B". It will return in C:D, so these columns must be empty:

```
Sub testHowManyIdenticNames()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Value2
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + 1
   Next i
   arrFin = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.Keys, dict.Items))
   
   sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

I also adapted the original code to return in "E2"...

Comment: how to set up the oldpath and newpath ?

Comment: i wrote it in this format

Comment: @Namlind You were talking about "Old folder" and "New folder". There you should place these folders path. How to use `ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\Rachid Mo\Desktop\Folder Z"`?  Don't you know what a folder path is? Don't you speak about real folders where you have the files to be moved/renamed and another one where to move them?

Comment: @Namlind  When you select the folder where the files in discussion exist, what do you see on top of the explorer window? There you can see the folder path... Did you try "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder Z", if the files exist there?

Comment: my question was about how to setup the path since i didn't see a place to put my folder path in oldpath line . so i set it up like this                                                              "oldPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder W":                                             newPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder Z"`"                               it give me an error though "bad file number or name" err 53

Comment: @Namlind No offence, but you should know where your files exist... It looks you really do not know what a folder path is. Don't you know where your files to be moved are? Are there in a folder named "Foder Z"? Only you have to know that... Did you try `oldPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder W"` and `newPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder Z"`? Of course, supposing that this is the correct path. **The one I said before you should see on top of the Explorer window when the respective folder is selected**.  `ThisWorkook.pat` is **the path of the workbook keeping the code**...

Comment: @Namlind Supposing that you will identify the path, do you now where to place the code and how to run it? Did you run any such code until now? If not, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? Do you know what the two mentioned applications are?

Comment: i know :D using dev mode in excel and select the sheet then put the code then run it almost like Vs code . i keep getting error = sub or function not defined at this line " Function newNm(strExisting As String, strFold As String) As String"

Comment: @Namlind You do not have copy the code in the sheet module... You have to copy it in a standard module. Go in VBE (`Alt + F111), in the left side expand the `VBAProject` having the name of your workbook, right click on `Microsoft Excel Object` and choose `Insert` - `Module`... Did you copy all the code I pasted above?

Comment: still same error sub or function not defined

Comment: mind doing this over AnyDesk ?

Comment: @Namlind It is late in my country and I was intending to close the laptop... Please send the AnyDesk ID and open a Notepad window to communicate on it. When I am connected, please, do not move the cursor. I will write a set a rules when connected. But send it fast, if possible, please.

Comment: @Namlind I edited my answer and place a procedure able to count the number of occurrences for all new names (in column B:B). Please, test it and send some feedback. According to your answer I will be able to adapt the function returning the new name when it already exists in the new folder...

Comment: adding that to the script got error : user-defined type not defined , in the line , Sub testHowManyIdenticNames()

Comment: @Namlind Yeah... It needs adding a reference, but I will adapt the code to work without that... I will do it in a minute. Adapted.

Comment: @Namlind I would also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer the question in a convenient way, we tick the left code side check box in ofer to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that solution works...